# awk : awk script to group by column with condition

Tags: awk

I have tab delimited file like following and I am trying to write a awk script

```
aaa_log-000592                    2     p      STARTED   7027691  21.7   a1
aaa_log-000592                    28    r      STARTED   7027815  21.7   a2
aaa_log-000592                    33    p      STARTED   7032607  21.7   a3
aaa_log-000592                    33    r      STARTED   7032607  21.7   a4
aaa_log-000592                    43    p      STARTED   7025709  21.7   a5
aaa_log-000592                    43    r      STARTED   7025709  21.7   a6
aaa_log-000595                    2     r      STARTED   7027691  21.7   a7
aaa_log-000598                    28    p      STARTED   7027815  21.7   a8
aaa_log-000599                    13    p      STARTED   7033090  21.7   a9
```

I am trying to count for 3rd column (p or r) and group by column 1

Output would be like

```
Col1                   Count-P  Count-R
aaa_log-000592            3     3                                      
aaa_log-000595            0     1       
aaa_log-000598            1     0        
aaa_log-000599            1     0
```

I can't find an example that would have IF condition with group by in awk.

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167280/awk-group-by-and-sum-column-values

Answer (score 0):

`awk`(more specifically, the GNU variant, `gawk`) has multi-dimensional arrays that can be indexed using input values (including character strings like in your example).  As such, you can count the values in the way you want by doing

```
{ 
    values[$3] = 1    # this line records the values in column three
    counts[$1][$3]++  # and this lines counts their frequency
}
```

The first line isn't strictly required, but it simplifies generating the output.

The only remaining part is to have an `END` clause that outputs the tabulated results.

```
END {
    # Print column headings
    printf "Col1              "
    for (v in values) {
        printf "  Count-%s", v
    }
    printf "\n"
      
    # Print tabulated results
    for (i in counts) {
        printf "%-20s", i
        for (v in values) {
            printf "    %d", counts[i][v]
        }
        printf "\n"
    }
}
```

Generating the `values` array handles the case when the values of column three may not be known (e.g., like when there's an error in your input).

If you're using a different `awk` implementation (like what you might find in macOS, for example), array indexing may be different (e.g., they are single-dimensional arrays, but indexed by a comma-separate list of indices).  This may add some additional complexity, but the idea is the same.

```
{
  files[$1] = 1
  values[$3] = 1
  counts[$1,$3]++
}

END {
    # Print column headings
    printf "Col1              "
    for (v in values) {
        printf "  Count-%s", v
    }
    printf "\n"

    # Print tabulated results
    for (f in files) {
        printf "%-20s", f
        for (v in values) {
            printf "    %d", counts[f,v]
        }
        printf "\n"
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am big confused: how would counts[$1][$3]++  will be able to count occurrence of "p" or "r". What I am trying to figure out is for a given value in column 1, how many times it has "p" and how many times it has "r" . For example : say column 1 value "ABC" has 2 'P' and 1 "r"

Comment: Let me try with a simpler problem first: Let's just count the number of *P*s and *R*s (and ignore which log file they're associated with).  Since `$3` for each line will contain either a *P*, or an *R*, we can use that value to index into an array of counts: in `awk` parlance `counts[$3]++`.  Now, if you print `counts["P"]`, you'll have the total number of *P*s in your input and likewise for *R*.

Comment: Now what you want is the number of *P*s and *R*s for each file in column 1.  In order to further refine the information we've collected, you can add another "level" to our array of counts to aggregate that data.  Building on the simpler case from above but adding that further classification, we add another index `counts[$3][$1]++`.  Then if you do `counts["P"]["aaa_log-000592"]` which tells you "the number of *P*s for log *aaa_log-000592*".

Comment: As I'm sure you've noticed, the indices in the discussion above are reversed from the answer's solution.  That's because you are collecting data about each log file, so it simplifies the logic a bit to make `$1`'s values the first index, and then index by `$3`. To generate the report format you want, you will need two loops: one going across the log files (the first index), and another loop for all the unique values in column 3 (the second index).  And the answer is a bit more general for the case when there's more than just *P*s and *R*s.  Hope that helps.